# Как задать скрипту определенное время исполнения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, время

Мне нужно выполнять разные функции в разное время. Как я могу реализовать что-то наподобие

```
time=["15:10:00","15:20:00","15:30:53","15:35:00","15:37:00","15:42:00","16:45:13","19:35:00","20:15:25","20:59:49"]
for t in time:
   #выполнить какую-то функцию
```

Сейчас у меня просто while True с проверкой на время. Есть ли какое-то элегантное решение?

Comment: Принципиально придумать своё решение или нужен результат? Просто очень много готовых решений как на уровне ОС, так и силами питоньих библиотек.

Comment: @Alpensin, результат нужен. А какие питоньи библиотеки?

Comment: Если можно вынести функции в отдельный код и запускать отдельно то можно просто пользоваться планировщиками задач (cron, Windows Scheduler). Если есть какой-то основной процесс и надо передавать таски на выполнение по ходу этого процесса, то celery самая известная.

Comment: @Alpensin, понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного подумав, я смог сделать это с помощью библиотек `datetime` и `pytz`

Получилось что-то по типу:

```py
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

time = [
    "15:10:00",
    "15:20:00",
    "15:30:53",
    "15:35:00",
    "15:37:00",
    "15:42:00",
    "16:45:13",
    "19:35:00",
    "20:15:25",
    "20:59:49"
    ]

while True:
    moscow_time = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow"))
    current_time = moscow_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if current_time in time:
        ...
```

другого варианта я придумать не смог